# Setting Environment Variable in vimrc

Tags: linux, bash, vim

I want to set an environment variable in vimrc. The pseudo code of what I want to do is below

```
if(file x exists in current directory)
path = get absolute path of file x
env = path
```

How can I do this in vimrc?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here? Why do you want to set environment variables in the vimrc? What does `env = path` mean?

Comment: by env = path I mean set the the value of the environment variable to the absolute path of the file. I am using cscope. I want to set CSCOPE_DB to different value when I am in a different project.

Comment: Does `:cscope add` (`:he E563`) do what you want here more directly?

Answer (score 8):

If you only need to affect the PATH in Vim, it's as easy as:

```
:let $PATH=...
```

Answer (score 2):

`XY`ing the problem a little bit vim supports the `:cscope add` command (see help entry `:h E563` among others) to control which cscope database is currently in use.

That should be a more direct (and more controllable) method of doing what is desired here.